# Specific criteria 'Greater than 50000' OR 'Less than -50000'

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

This is what I have so far. There are a couple of amendments I want to make, that I don't completely understand how to do;

1. On line 3, I want my 'Copying criteria' to be 'Greater than 50000' or 'Less than 50000'.
2. How can I specify the cells on Sheet2 where the first item is copied to? For example, Sheet2! B10?
3. How can I then restrict the columns copied from the row on Sheet 1 which meets my criteria to (for example) columns A, B, E, F, H, I, O, & AG from Sheet1?

```
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row

    For i = 2 To a

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = **>50000 OR <50000** Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActivateSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        End if

    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: To your title question, you have to do two conditional statements: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value >50000 or Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value < -50000 Then`.

Comment: `Abs(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value) > 50000`

Comment: The if statement you have in your code does not show a negative... it shows <50000...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `Abs()` function and have one check only:

and use `Range` property of `Worksheet` object to *select* wanted columns in given row by means of `Intersect()` method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim a As Long, i As Long
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2") ' set a worksheet object for destination sheet

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' reference Sheet1
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' get referenced sheet column A row index of last not empty cell
        For i = 2 To a
            If Abs(.Cells(i, 3).Value) > 50000 Then ' if cell value in current row index and column 3 is greater than 50000 or less then -500000
                Intersect(.Rows(i), .Range("A:B , E:F, H:I, O:O, AG:AG")).Copy
                sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my purpose. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `x1Up` instead of `xlUp`.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 2)
        If cell.Value > -50000 Or cell.Value < 50000 Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                cell.EntireRow.Range("A1:B1,E1:F1,H1,I1,O1,AG1").Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End With
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: `Option Explicit` strikes again!

Comment: @AJD lol... I should have mentioned that and a few other things

Comment: Yeah, easy to miss after one has done it for the 1001th time :-)